# Trigger to limit products being added across all opportunities

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, opportunity-lineitem

I have a use case where I need to limit the number of two products that can be added across all opportunities. For example "Product A" and "Product B" can only be cumulatively added across all opportunities 4 times. How can I modify this existing trigger to accomplish this? This existing trigger also only looks at newly added products, how can it be changed for products that are already associated to an opportunity?

```
trigger LimitProduct on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    
    set<id> oppIds = new set<id>();
    
    for(opportunitylineitem oid : trigger.new){
        oppIds.add(oid.Product2Id);
    }
    
    Set<Id> extras = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT Product2Id Id
        FROM OpportunityLineItem
        WHERE Product2Id In: oppIds
        GROUP BY Product2Id
        HAVING SUM(quantity) > 3
    ]).keySet();
    
        for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        if(extras.contains(record.Product2Id)) {
           record.addError('Error message here.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what part of that didn't work the way you wanted?

Comment: How can I outline which Product or Product Family I'd want this trigger to perform on?

Answer (score 0):

A trigger won't work, as the data is already committed/saved to the database. You would need to perform queries (perhaps from a Batchable class) and scrub all the existing data as a one-time execution.